# jQuery effect() and animate() methods at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, shake

I need to shake div and animate its background-color color at the same time.

Here is the JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/EUz4z/

```
$("#test").effect("shake", {}, 500 ).css("background-color","red").animate({backgroundColor: old_bg}, 500 );
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `queue: false` option:

http://jsfiddle.net/ysFcD/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#but").click(function(){
        old_bg=$("#test").css("background-color");
        $("#test").effect("shake", {  }, 500 )
            .css("background-color","red")
            .animate({backgroundColor: old_bg}, {duration: 500, queue: false } );
    })
});
```